# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in retrieving html string from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i am working to save a html snippet into the mongodb database, the save operation is successful however retrieving the data from mongo causes a failure 'TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON'.

the code is pretty simple

```
let database;
let connection;

exports.connectDatabase = function(MONGO_URL,DB_NAME) {
  MongoClient.connect(  MONGO_URL,  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
      database = client.db(DB_NAME);
      connection = client;
    }
  );
};

exports.getDatabase = function(){
  return database;
};



exports.saveHtml = async function(req, res) {
  try{
    await getDatabase().collection('htmls').insertOne({name:req.body.title,  html:req.body.content });
    res.send('success');
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    res.json(404);
    return;
  }
}

exports.getSavedHtmls =  async function(req,res){
  try{
    let html = await getDatabase().collection('htmls').find({});
    res.send(html);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    res.json(404);
    return;
  }
}
```

the error is

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/Users/xisizhe/Documents/server/node_modules/_express@4.17.1@express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
```

How would I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDatabase().collection('htmls').find({})` returns a [FindCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/FindCursor.html).

You will need to call [toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray) to get an array of documents that can be converted to JSON.